# How to use "column" to center a chart?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I was wondering what the best way to sort a chart using the `column` command to center each column instead of the default left aligned column was. I have been using the `column -t filename` command.

Current Output:

```
Label1        label2
Anotherlabel  label2442
label152      label42242
label78765    label373737737
```

Desired Output:  Something like this

```
   Label1        label2
Anotherlabel    label2442
  label152      label42242
 label78765   label373737737
```

Basically, I want it to be centered instead of left aligned.

Comment: You'll probably have to write this yourself using awk, python, or something similar. I wrote it for fun in python here: https://gist.github.com/sr105/04063c756db154b5df383892c021a7fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk solution:

```
# Collect all lines in "data", keep track of maximum width for each field
{
    data[NR] = $0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        max[i] = length($i) > max[i] ? length($i) : max[i]
}

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) {
        # Split record into array "arr"
        split(data[i], arr)
        # Loop over array
        for (j = 1; j <= NF; ++j) {
            # Calculate amount of padding required
            pad = max[j] - length(arr[j])
            # Print field with appropriate padding, see below
            printf "%*s%*s%s", length(arr[j]) + int(pad/2), arr[j], \
                               pad % 2 == 0 ? pad/2 : int(pad/2) + 1, "", \
                               j == NF ? "" : "  "
        }
        # Newline at end of record
        print ""
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
$ awk -f centre.awk infile
   Label1         label2
Anotherlabel    label2442
  label152      label42242
 label78765   label373737737
```

The `printf` statement uses padding with dynamic widths:

- The first `%*s` takes care of left padding and the data itself: `arr[j]` gets printed and padded to a total width of `length(arr[j]) + int(pad/2)`.
- The second `%*s` prints the empty string, left padded to half of the total padding required. `pad % 2 == 0 ? pad/2 : int(pad/2) + 1` checks if the total padding was an even number, and if not, adds an extra space.
- The last `%s` prints `j == NF ? "" : "  "`, i.e., two spaces, unless we're at the last field.

Some older awks don't support the `%*s` syntax, but the formatting string can be assembled like `width = 5; "%" width "s"` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python program to do what you want. It's probably too hard to do in bash, so you'll need to use a custom program or awk script. Basic algorithm:

- count number of columns
- [optional] make sure each line has the same number of columns
- figure out the maximum length of data for each column
- print each line using the max lengths

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def column():
    # Read file and split each line into fields (by whitespace)
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        lines = [line.split() for line in f]
    # Check that each line has the same number of fields
    num_fields = len(lines[0])
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        if len(line) != num_fields:
            print('Line {} has wrong number of columns: expected {}, got {}'.format(n, num_fields, len(line)))
            sys.exit(1)
    # Calculate the maximum length of each field
    max_column_widths = [0] * num_fields
    for line in lines:
        line_widths = (len(field) for field in line)
        max_column_widths = [max(z) for z in zip(max_column_widths, line_widths)]
    # Now print them centered using the max_column_widths
    spacing = 4
    format_spec = (' ' * spacing).join('{:^' + str(n) + '}' for n in max_column_widths)
    for line in lines:
        print(format_spec.format(*line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    column()
```